# My D drive just disappeared from my computer

Tags: windows

My D drive just disappeared from my computer. I tried the chkdsk option in the command prompt chkdsk D: /r . i got the answer . the chkdsk cannot run the volume is in use by another process. chkdsk may run if this volume is dismounted first. ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID. now am not sure if i shud say yes or no. Please help I have had my whole life's work on D Drive and now it just disappeared on me. :'(

Comment: Fire up "Disk Management". Is the drive showing as a partition without a label?

Comment: Not to be mean, but please take this as a valuable lesson in backing up your data.

Comment: @spikey_richie no its not showing anything

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean Thanks .. but not so recently my external hard disk drive  got fried .. am learning my lessons very well lolz

Comment: If you restart your computer, does the drive re-appear?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean I tried that and I restored system to a previous point as well. so far nothing! Now I came across this software Minitool partition recovery wizard. lets see if that helps... keeping my fingers crossed

Comment: Is it a mechanical drive (HDD) or an electronic drive (SSD, NVMe, etc)? If mechanical, can you feel it spinning? Is the drive seen in the BIOS?

Comment: Surprised nobody has asked this yet: Does your harddrive appear in your BIOS? You can usually enter the BIOS during startup by pressing delete, f2 or f10. (before the windows logo)

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management. What else can you tell us about D:? Was it a partition on the same physical drive that C: is on? If not, what make and model is the drive? How is it connected to the PC? What type of PC is it (desktop/tower/notebook/...)?

Answer (score -1):

The chelkdsk error 
ALL OPENED HANDLES TO THIS VOLUME WOULD THEN BE INVALID. 
Comes as it dismounts or delete the drive letter or hide the partition before checking and after complementing it remounts or re adds the partition or drive letter but if chkdsk fails or closed in between by you or some app  or hardware powers eroor or malware or by any reason it does not automatically mount or launch the drive letter

1. First probability is the partition is hidden or changed drive letter or hidden or not mounted
2. Its chances that HDD is failing
3. Its chance that partition is corrupted

Don't be worried there is solutions for all problems

Firstly hope for the best if partition is hidden or not mounted then is simple and you can mount or assign drive letter by following mehod

Method 1. Unhide partitions with Disk Management Tool without a drive letter

1.Right-click on This PC/My Computer and click on Manage;
 Or

1. . If you like it, you can also use it to open Disk Management. Press the Win + R keys on your keyboard to open Run, enter the command

diskmgmt.msc

and then press Enter or OK.

2. Select New Volume - the partition which you've hidden previously and
3. right-clicking it by selecting Change Drive Letter and Paths for New Volume;

[image: disk management of windows]

4. Tab Add to assign the drive letter for the partition to unhide it;

[image: disk management unhide partotion]

5. Assign the drive letter for the hidden partition such as F and hit OK;

See videos for more help

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VbPE39xhkP8

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xS_P198ykkY